# How can I adapt Cheet.NET to bind to my C# Form?

Tags: c#, winforms, nuget-package

So I was having trouble setting up a keybind to do something in my project (Right Alt + Left Control)

And I tried using an API called Cheet.NET which says it can easily adapt a project and allow making custom "konami" codes which can call functions.

Cheet.NET's (Small) Documentation: http://jamiehumphries.github.io/Cheet.NET/

So I installed it using the NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio, Saved, and Reloaded my project.

Came back, tried attempting to write a simple keybind, and I already got a lot of errors from the initialization code:

```cs
// Initialization
var cheet = new Cheet();
myUIElement.PreviewKeyDown += cheet.OnKeyDown;

cheet.Map("↑ ↑ ↓ ↓", () => { Debug.WriteLine("Voilà!"); } );
```

this is where Im placing the code:

```cs
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        // Initialization
        var cheet = new Cheet();
        myUIElement.PreviewKeyDown += cheet.OnKeyDown;

        cheet.Map("↑ ↑ ↓ ↓", () => { Debug.WriteLine("Voilà!"); });

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

It fails to recognize a lot of the code, and gives me alot of calculation errors too:

> Invalid token '+=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
>   type expected
>   Tuple must contain atleast Two Elements
>   Invalid token '"↑ ↑ ↓ ↓"' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

I heard I was supposed to "bind" the package to my project, but Im not sure how to do so.

Appreciate any future help.

Comment: The code in the question does not match the indicated errors.

Comment: ha, well.... where you had it placed was *right*. And  matches the indicated error.

Comment: so what's the error now? seems futile to just update our answers and take downvotes later on for previous answers that were trying to guess the issue from what you had said up to then

Comment: BTW from what I can tell there is no implementation for Windows Forms. Only the WPF implementation.

Comment: @GeorgeBirbilis I got it working by adding using Cheet.NET.core; and its semi working now, but Im still getting 1 error: Using the generic type 'Cheet<T>' requires 1 type arguments

Comment: this means you can't just type-in new Cheet(), but have to use new Cheet<SomeDataType> probably - wonder how the WPF demo mentioned in other answer below uses it

Comment: btw, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25696507/in-winforms-previewkeydown-never-fired-for-any-key if you want to enable key preview in WinForms

Comment: @TaylorSpark ironically, my comment above answers your comment below it.

Comment: @Jamiec if they didnt support .NET, why is there a wpf and .NET package in the package manager, not just a WPF pack

Comment: They *do* support .NET. They dont support windows forms. You could write an implementation for winforms.

Comment: so this was all useless?

Comment: pretty much, except you could extend it to support winforms - even submit it back to the github repo. Thats what Open Source is all about.

Comment: nope it should be easy, see my answer now, try using the WPF version, else try the Core one and use Cheet<Key>() instead of Cheer()

Comment: @Jamiec Hell i aint know how to do that...

Comment: but you have to turn on key preview for WinForms, see the link on my comment above

Comment: @GeorgeBirbilis the `Cheet<T>` in core is abstract. And the WPF version doesnt work in Winforms as its a different API for key handling.

Comment: they could extend the Core like the WPF version does (no need to first contribute their version, can do it later) in a class for WinForms. However the WPF version seems to just be using System.Windows.Input and maybe addition of PresentationBase.dll from WPF could work out of the box or with WinForms/WPF interop controls if needed (see https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37360/WinForms-WPF-Interop)

Comment: ...however I assume it's easier to adapt the code based on the key preview code for WinForms in the url I had in above comment (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25696507/in-winforms-previewkeydown-never-fired-for-any-key)

Comment: @TaylorSpark I wrote you a very simple, and almost completely untested, implementation for winforms. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At its most simplest, you can almost copy/paste the Wpf implementation from github and change to using the right eventhandlers/enums for windows forms:

```
using CheetNET.Core;
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Cheet : Cheet<System.Windows.Forms.Keys>
{
    private static readonly Regex LetterKeysNamePattern = new Regex(@"^[a-z]$");
    private static readonly Regex NumberKeysNamePattern = new Regex(@"^[0-9]$");
    private static readonly Regex KeyspadNumberKeysNamePattern = new Regex(@"^kp_[0-9]$");
    private static readonly Regex FunctionKeysNamePattern = new Regex(@"^(?:f[1-9]|f1[0-2])$");

    private PreviewKeyDownEventArgs lastHandledEvent;

    public virtual void OnKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e == lastHandledEvent)
        {
            return;
        }
        OnKeyDown(e.KeyCode);
        lastHandledEvent = e;
    }

    protected override Keys GetKey(string KeysName)
    {
        if (LetterKeysNamePattern.IsMatch(KeysName))
        {
            return ParseKey(KeysName.ToUpper());
        }
        if (NumberKeysNamePattern.IsMatch(KeysName))
        {
            return ParseKey("D" + KeysName);
        }
        if (KeyspadNumberKeysNamePattern.IsMatch(KeysName))
        {
            return ParseKey(KeysName.Replace("kp_", "NumPad"));
        }
        if (FunctionKeysNamePattern.IsMatch(KeysName))
        {
            return ParseKey(KeysName.ToUpper());
        }
        switch (KeysName)
        {
            case "left":
            case "L":
            case "←":
                return Keys.Left;
            case "up":
            case "U":
            case "↑":
                return Keys.Up;
            case "right":
            case "R":
            case "→":
                return Keys.Right;
            case "down":
            case "D":
            case "↓":
                return Keys.Down;
            case "backspace":
                return Keys.Back;
            case "tab":
                return Keys.Tab;
            case "enter":
                return Keys.Enter;
            case "return":
                return Keys.Return;
            case "shift":
            case "⇧":
                return Keys.LShiftKey;
            case "control":
            case "ctrl":
            case "^":
                return Keys.LControlKey;
            case "alt":
            case "option":
            case "⌥":
                return Keys.Alt;
            case "command":
            case "⌘":
                return Keys.LWin;
            case "pause":
                return Keys.Pause;
            case "capslock":
                return Keys.CapsLock;
            case "esc":
                return Keys.Escape;
            case "space":
                return Keys.Space;
            case "pageup":
                return Keys.PageUp;
            case "pagedown":
                return Keys.PageDown;
            case "end":
                return Keys.End;
            case "home":
                return Keys.Home;
            case "insert":
                return Keys.Insert;
            case "delete":
                return Keys.Delete;
            case "equal":
            case "=":
                return Keys.Oemplus;
            case "comma":
            case ",":
                return Keys.Oemcomma;
            case "minus":
            case "-":
                return Keys.OemMinus;
            case "period":
            case ".":
                return Keys.OemPeriod;
            case "kp_multiply":
                return Keys.Multiply;
            case "kp_plus":
                return Keys.Add;
            case "kp_minus":
                return Keys.Subtract;
            case "kp_decimal":
                return Keys.Decimal;
            case "kp_divide":
                return Keys.Divide;
        }
        throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("Could not map Keys named '{0}'.", KeysName));
    }

    private static Keys ParseKey(string KeysName)
    {
        return (Keys)Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), KeysName);
    }
}
```

Then, so long as you put the code inside the form load handler, it works as expected:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    var cheet = new Cheet();
    PreviewKeyDown += cheet.OnKeyDown;
    cheet.Map("c h e a t", () => { MessageBox.Show("Voilà!"); });

    base.OnLoad(e);
}
```

Comment: maybe consider contribution to that repo

Comment: @GeorgeBirbilis 100%. Except does anyone *really* use winforms any more.

Comment: it's nicer for novices and with a nice WYSIWYG editor that follows the PME (Property-Method-Event) pattern that I like a lot (from Delphi and classic VB). If somebody ported it to .NET Core for use in Linux etc. it could become more popular nowadays too ;-)

Comment: _cries in legacy UIs_

Comment: Also @Jamiec I just find winforms easy to use, Ive never even heard of WPF until recently. I also have almost no idea how to use it

Comment: One more thing, I uh.... Dont really know how to use your code. I tried adding it to its own class file, with and without cheet.net.core installed.

Comment: @TaylorSpark you install `Cheet.Core` nuget package and put the class above in its own file in your project.

Comment: @Jamiec I tried that and it just gives me tons of errors, saying things in the cs file are incorrect. 
Do I have to put "using Cheet.NET.Core;" on the top? Im just going to try it

Comment: @TaylorSpark I have updated answer with required `using` statements for that file

Comment: @Jamiec Thankyou, It seems to be working now, Now i gotta install vs2019 for a couple hours and be able to see if itll build correctly, And Run... Ive been stuck in vs 2017 forever now...

Comment: I tried putting your protected onLoad into the form load and it gave } errors. I also just tried putting the cheet script into the form load and it didnt give errors, but failed to do squat.

Answer (score 2):

**Update (since you've added error output to the question):**

> Invalid token '+=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
>   type expected

you can't just place C# code at the top-level in your class, there's a minimal structure you have to follow. You can place such code in a constructor method or some other method or some static initialization block for the class (if you only refer static stuff in your code)

**Next Update (after newer error):**

> Using the generic type 'Cheet' requires 1 type arguments

you're using the generic package instead of the Wpf one where they do:

```
public class Cheet : Cheet<Key>, ICheet
```

quite unfortunate I think that they use the same class name

so need a different using to refer to this class instead (see its namespace, it is CheetNET.Wpf): 
https://github.com/jamiehumphries/Cheet.NET/blob/master/Cheet.Wpf/Cheet.cs and not the CheetNET Core one from https://github.com/jamiehumphries/Cheet.NET/blob/master/Cheet.Core/Cheet.cs that you seem to be using

**More info:**

The only WPF stuff from the version of that Cheet class for WPF seems to be System.Windows.Input. Can probably just use it with WinForms/WPF interop (see https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37360/WinForms-WPF-Interop), but I'd consider writing a similar class to the WPF one for WinForms. See [In Winforms, PreviewKeyDown() never fired for ANY key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25696507/in-winforms-previewkeydown-never-fired-for-any-key) on how to enable and do key preview for WinForms

**Old reply:**

If you just installed the package in the solution (there was a dropdown I think in the console to pick the target), make sure you also right-click the project in Visual Studio and manage its Nuget packages.

Can also right-click the solution/top node in the Solution/Source Explorer pane and from the Nuget packages management window select the projects to which a specific installed package is made available.

Note that there's a separate tab for online/available, installed and updates in the manager.

Anyway, no need to use the console when you're novice, use the UI, much easier and user-friendly

Comment: @jamiec took the time to post a port to WinForms

Answer (score 2):

There's a WPF demo app in the repository, and it has you initializing in a Window constructor:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    var cheet = new Cheet();
    PreviewKeyDown += cheet.OnKeyDown;

    cheet.Map("↑ ↑ ↓ ↓ ← → ← → b a", () => { WriteLine("Voilà!"); });

    cheet.Map("i d d q d", () => {
        WriteLine("god mode enabled");
    });
    [etc.]
```

So you handle the `PreviewKeyDown` event with `cheet.OnKeyDown`, and presumably in `OnKeyDown` Cheet will loop through its mappings and look for one that fits.

I set up a test WinForms project and added Cheet.NET, and it looks like you've got a bit of work ahead if you want to use it with WinForms.

`Cheet.Core` has a `Cheet<T>` class, but it's abstract.  It looks like `T` is intended to be a "key" type.  The Cheet.Wpf library has a `Cheet` class inheriting from `Cheet<Key>`, using the WPF `Key` type.

It appears that you'd need to create your own `Cheet` class inheriting (most likely) from `Cheet<System.Windows.Forms.Keys>`.

I guess the question at this point is which is more work: To implement Cheet for WinForms, or to just start your project over in WPF.

Comment: but how do i do it in .NET forms

Comment: @TaylorSpark I've added more details.  Unfortunately it looks like out-of-the-box it won't work with WinForms.